# Set child height dynamically in scrollview

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollview

I have a child layout within a **scrollview** that contains many objects that move around depending on their layout size (having attributes like centerVertical=true). The problem is that the **scrollview won't begin scrolling** until the layout becomes as small as possible, which makes many of these objects overlap each other. I'm trying to correct this by setting the child height to a custom value, however the entire layout becomes jumbled then. I have fillviewport=true, I'm just trying to find a way to control the height of the child inside the scrollview because it is deciding to make it too small by itself. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your xml file